# Using jQuery for AJAX with ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, webforms

Anyone know of a link to a good article/tutorial for getting started using jQuery for AJAX calls rather than ASP.NET AJAX? I'm trying to avoid using UpdatePanels entirely in this app, which I haven't been able to accomplish in the past.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you do not want to use Update Panels? I am in the same boat and am just wondering your reasoning. Trying to determine ASP.Net AJAX vs jQuery (which I love) or a combination of both...

Comment: @AndyBrudtkuhl The problem with update panels is that post-back the entire view-state, trigger the entire server-page to render, download the entire web-page, and then throw away all the work done by the server - replacing just the contents of the panel. Also, when the panel contents are replaced, the user loses the focus on the control they were in.

Answer (score 6):

The most complete article I've ever found about this topic is [ASP.NET and jQuery to the Max](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95525/ASP-NET-and-jQuery-to-the-Max).

It avoids update panel, script manager and viewstate.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few links:

- [A Look Into JQuery API (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090414104717/http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/407_A%20Look%20Into%20JQuery%20Ajax%20API.aspx)
- [Using FireBug Profiler to Dig Deep into MS AJAX and JQuery API
  (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090609194456/http://azamsharp.com/Posts/83_Using_FireBug_Profiler_to_Dig_Deep_into_MS_AJAX_and_JQuery_API.aspx)
- [On Demand Loading Using JQuery Ajax API (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090217113039/http://azamsharp.com/Posts/74_On_Demand_Loading_Using_JQuery_Ajax_API.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Damien Edwards just gave an awesome talk on this topic at the recent MIX11 conference. You can [watch the video online (archived - click any download links below the player)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110724072836/http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/FRM12) and download his code. He developed a jquery-UI extenders project that works the same way that ASP.NET AJAX toolkit works, but just extends normal controls/tags/elements with jQuery functionality. The project is on [CodePlex (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190801214144/https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=jquery).