# asp.net getting a value of a textbox that is not yet created

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, textbox

I have an input type-text that is created dynamically via asp.net after a div is being clicked on:

```
divID.innerHtml = "<input type='text' runat='server' id='box' value='' />";
```

what i am trying to do is when the div is clicked again, to get the value of the textbox in asp.net.

the problem is - the textbox does not exist so the compiler gives me an error for trying to use its name.

Is there a way to do this?

i also thought that maybe there is a way to somehow use jquery to pass the value to asp.net.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202538/using-jquery-for-ajax-with-asp-net-webforms

Comment: You can look at `Request.Form["box"]` to get this on the server.

Comment: @InvisibleBacon yes, but it doesn't say how (and if) i can use ajax to pass a value from jquery to asp.net - just the other way.

Comment: @MikeChristensen should i write any thing special in my textbox for that to work? (runat..? name..? put it in a form..?)

Comment: It would need to be in the form being submitted, as well as have a `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than create your textbox as `HTML`, create the control and add it to your page.

I.E

```
  ''IN VB
  Dim tb as New TextBox() with {.ID = "box", .ClientIDMode =  UI.ClientIDMode.Static }

  // In C#
  TextBox tb = new TextBox {
    ID = "box",
     ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Static
  };
```

Using `ClientIDMode=Static` will ensure the ID you set in the code-behind will be the one rendered to the HTML, rather than .net changing it.

Then add this to your divID

```
   divID.Controls.Add(tb)
```

You will now have access to it on postback by. In your postback method you will need to `FindControl` to get the control - this is because its not a known control on your page. I am using FindControl on the divID, this will look inside that div for the textbox we created earlier.

```
 ''VB
 Dim tb as TextBox = CType(divID.FindControl("box"), TextBox)

 // C#
TextBox tb = (TextBox)divID.FindControl("box");
```

You will be also able to access this TextBox's value via JQuery by calling `$("#box").val()` should you need.

Comment: do you mean when you post back? or by jquery>?

Comment: I did actually put the answer there for both postback AND jquery - perhaps re-read the answer... :)

Comment: basically when the div bellow is pressed, but i have it set up so it will just refresh the page using jquery (and therefor calling Page_Load()) - how can i get the value in the Page_Load function? like when i have a div with a runat=server i write `string st=divId.innerText`

Comment: after `TextBox tb = (TextBox)divID.FindControl("box");` can i just go `tb.value` (or something like that)?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. I am VERY lost as to what you are trying to achieve. I can only suggest you try to re-form your question so it makes more sense. You would cause a postback by clicking a button (for example) - it is in the method of this button click where you get the value - not the page load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a more ASP-centric approach, such as that posted by Darren.

However, *all* form inputs are submitted for processing during a PostBack (full or partial).

Thus, if a text input control with a *name* `box`<sup>1</sup> is added to the HTML `form` - dynamically or from a previous request - then the submitted form value can be accessed via [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) in the corresponding PostBack:

```
string boxValue = Request.Form["box"];
```

Note that this only gets a value submitted with a form, should it exist; it does *not* create any magical code-behind object or otherwise affect the Control Tree. The Control Tree might be altered as a side-effect of receiving new values such as adding new controls to the page this PostBack ..

---

<sup>1</sup> HTML form inputs should have a name attribute; the id attribute is not used for HTML form submission. Also, name attributes can be duplicated which result in "control arrays". To access these, which are submitted as multiple values, use [Request.Form.GetValues(name)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx).