# Execute C# code while using .load jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Again, I've looked around to try to find some posts on this and there are many but none that address my specific question (that I could find).

What I am looking : I have a projects and it loads different pages (.aspx) in an iframe dynamically. Now I am trying to remove iframe and add a div and load aspx pages inside that div, using this :

```
$("#containerDiv").load("test/default.aspx", function () {
});
```

it loads aspx page easily but I am unable to execute `C#` code which is written in `default.aspx.cs` may be its not a good practice but I want to know is there any solution of my problem.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202538/using-jquery-for-ajax-with-asp-net-webforms). I think you have to load an .asmx file, not an .aspx one

Comment: As far my knowledge It is not going to work. As you are trying. Moreover if it is a part of your application then you can do trick (`jquery ajax`, `httphandler` etc) to keep the page working.

Comment: @Shekhar, You are right, this would be my last step if I'll not get any solution.

Comment: Also if you load a new `.aspx` page so there will be two `form tags` which is not allowed in `asp.net` and on postback you will get exception.

Answer (score 0):

`$.load` will not your c# code why because it load only the contents of your `aspx` page not of `aspx.cs`. 
Use user controls instead.

If need help how to implement user control refer [this](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/usercontrols/usercontrols.aspx) link.