# How to call service page method from Java Script file when we use friendly URL in our website?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The following code works just fine without *FriendlyUR* turned on for an ASP.Net Web Forms project:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{}",      
    url: "bloglistService.aspx/showpost'",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data, status) {
        varList = (data.d);
```

Now, if the friendly urls are added using the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls`, the same code would not work. As FriendlyUrls are turned on, I changed the URL in jquery ajax call to be *"/bloglistService/showpost"*, until it is not working 
I am struggling to find out why this would not work, the only thing I changed was adding the nuget package for the FriendlyUrls!

Am I doing something wrong or missing something here? Has anyone encountered the same scenario for their project? If so, can you please answer how this can be solved? Thanks a bunch for taking time to read and reply.

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663858/jquery-ajax-calls-not-working-with-asp-net-web-forms-when-friendlyurls-are-added

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this is not working for me

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolve() should work for you. Please check the accepted answer from above link.

Comment: After using this, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" exception occur.

Comment: Just change the URL to url: '<%= ResolveUrl("bloglistService.aspx/showpost") %>', and ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs change:settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
(Or just comment the line)

Comment: After doing this FriendlyUrl is not working