# $.post is not send data to web form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .post

Function:

```
$.post("/SurveyResult.aspx", {
    test: 'testing',
}).done(function (data) {
    alert("Data Updated");
});
```

ServerSide of :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {    
    var formValue = Request.Form["test"];
 }
```

function is posting well But I'm getting null value of test at server side. Do not know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a web method on the server side to receive this ajax call, it can't be done on the page load since this should be an ajax call not a full page refresh.

To know more about web methods:
 [Using jQuery for AJAX with ASP.NET Webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202538/using-jquery-for-ajax-with-asp-net-webforms)
[Calling a webmethod with jquery in asp.net webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms)

And personally I used to use services with ajax instead of page methods in asp.net forms : https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/ASP-NET-Site-Videos/how-do-i-make-ajax-calls-using-jquery

Comment: I'm posting from a different form to `SurveyResult.aspx`. so it can be done in page load. i have been doing this in other applications but don't know why not getting any data]

Comment: aha, this is different then, ok did you try get instead of post?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mark the method on the aspx code behind as a webmethod and specify the same when you are posting to it.On the client, you will need to make the following change:

```
$.post("/SurveyResult.aspx/OnSubmit", {
test: 'testing',
}).done(function (data) {
alert("Data Updated");
});
```

Also, in your code-behind you will need to expose the method you want to be called to handle the post.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string OnSubmit(string test)
{
   var value = test;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently not posting form encoded data but a json string. If you want to keep the aspx as the end point and access the variables using the `Form` collection then you will have to change your ajax call to post form encoded data and specify that in the header of the http call.

```
$.post({
    url: "/SurveyResult.aspx",
    data: $.param({test: 'testing'}),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).done(function (data) {
  alert("Data Updated");
});
```

See also [param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) which makes passing / transforming objects as a part of the request data a little easier to write. You could also replace it with this hard coded string.

```
data: "test=testing",
```